# Openni rosmake failing on OSX

Tags: openni, rosmake, macos-snowleopard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edited to add: I see that I need to install the original branch of ni, not the master, so I've done that now. MacPorts won't install libusb-devel for me, so that's the latest problem.

OS X 10.6.6 Snow Leopard. openni from https://github.com/ros-pkg-git/ni.git as in the [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni).

```
rosmake --pre-clean openni --rosdep-install
```

This results in an error (I've replaced the actual path with ~):

```
[ rosmake ] rosdep successfully installed all system dependencies                                                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> openni [ make clean ]                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< openni [PASS] [ 0.06 seconds ]                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] Starting >>> tools/rospack                                                                                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Finished <<< tools/rospack                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> openni [ make ]                                                                                                                                           
[ rosmake ] All 19 linespenni: 0.7 sec ]                                                                                                                  [ 1 Active 0/1 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ### Patching the main Makefile for OpenNI...
  ~/ros/ni/openni
  ### Patching the output library for OpenNI...
  ~/ros/ni/openni
  ### Patching the output library for all library Modules...
  ~/ros/ni/openni
  ### Patching the output location for all samples...
  ~/ros/ni/openni
  ### Patching the output location for all tools...
  ~/ros/ni/openni
  ### Patching the location of modules.xml...
  ~/ros/ni/openni
  ### Patching the location of SamplesConfig.xml...
  ~/ros/ni/openni
  cd build/openni/Platform/Linux-x86/Build && make core samples && cd -
  make -C OpenNI 
  make[2]: *** libnCFLAGS+=-O3: Is a directory.  Stop.
  make[1]: *** [OpenNI] Error 2
```

Some troubleshooting:
Obviously something is not being escaped properly and the wrong things are being interpreted as directory names. I find two cases where libnCFLAGS+=-O3 and also -msse2nBIN_DIR= are being created as subdirs within ~/ros/ni/openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux-x86/Build/OpenNI/:

1. pre—clean (which also generates similar errors as above)
2. the last cited command in
   the error output: cd
   build/openni/Platform/Linux-x86/Build
   && make core samples && cd -

In both cases the -msse... dir also replicates the path /User/username/ros/ni/openni/

This gets beyond my capabilities, but it looks to me like make is having the problem in both cases.
Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9298/openni-rosmake-failing-on-osx/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a problem that has historically been common with ros & openni.

The problem is that OSX sed works very differntly from ubuntu sed. The former is the BSD sed flavor, the latter is the GNU sed flavor. In BSD sed, there is basically no way to encode an "endline" (\n) character. In BSD sed, \n means "literally an n" which is why you get all of these weird n characters everywhere.

The solution is to install gsed (gnu sed) using macports (sudo port install gsed), and then to set a SED_EXE variable in all of the bash patch scripts. It can be set to sed by default, but on darwin platforms should be set to gsed.

Then do a global replace in the script from sed to $SED_EXE or something like that.

Finally, once you have patched the patches, send your patch to the good folks at WG, so it helps the rest of us =)

---

Originally posted by [Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/237/nick/) with karma: 93 on 2011-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/237/nick/) on 2011-03-06**:
Sure, good luck and let me know if you have difficulties.

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-03-06**:
Nick, Many thanks for the reply. I will take a shot at what you suggest. (PS This "comment" format I am now using is woefully inadequate for this forum.)